# Receiving unexpected output

Tags: c++, reference, storage

Here when I run below code :

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//static int x;
int& fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    cout<<"in fun"<<endl;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**op:**

```
in fun
in fun
30
```

Above the fun() get called two times first time because of `fun() = 30;`
and second time because of `cout << fun()<<endl` statement.

If the function is getting called separately for `cout << fun()<<endl` the value printed should be `10` not `30` or I am missing something?

Because both the function calls are different.

And when I declare x as global static:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
static int x;
int& fun()
{
    x = 10;
    cout<<"in fun"<<" "<<x<<endl;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout<<fun()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**op:**

```
in fun
in fun
10
```

I just want to know the reason, why the code behaves like that?
Why first case generates unexpected O/P?

And when I use auto x as:

```
int& fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    cout<<"in fun"<<endl;
    return x;
}
```

it gives segmentation fault.
Please explain this to me, I am unable to get it.

Comment: Please, do not **ever** tag **C** in your C++ questions.

Comment: 30 from the first case is what I would expect. You call `fun()` which returns a reference to a static int that has been initialised to 10, then overwrite that value with 30, so that's what gets printed. The second example is unclear: please include the whole modified program. A seg-fault in the last example is not surprising since you return a reference to a variable that has gone out of scope.

Comment: Second example is not clear, if you really replace local static with global static behaviour is the same as in the first example. Third example is obvious, you should not return reference to local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When the static is local, you initialize it to 10 on first function call. Then you assign 30 in main. The second call does not modify the static object because there are no assignments; there is only initialization which is done once.
2. You replaced the initialization of the local static in the function with `x = 10;`, which is an assignment operation. Therefore the assignment within the function call will be after the assignment in main.
3. You return a reference to a local object of automatic storage duration. The object is destroyed after the function returns. Any access to that object after the function returns has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun() = 30;
```

calls `fun()` initializes `x` to `10`.A reference to `x` gets returned which sets `x` to `30`.

```
 cout << fun()<<endl;
```

calls `fun()`, `x` is not re-initialized and value of `x` which is `30` is returned.

```
int& fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    cout<<"in fun"<<endl;
    return x;
}
```

here you return a reference to a local variable which goes out of scope when `fun()` ends, accessing that reference in main is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: You're returning reference of x, so     fun() = 30 changes the value of x.
Case 2: The second call to fun reinstates the value of x to 10.
Case 3: The scope of x is limited to the function. It should not be used outside the function.